# R Shiny linked checkboxGroupInputs

Tags: r, shiny

Hello everybody,

I need your help please : I have a dataframe named data_test, you can reproduce it with these lines :

```
 PC<-c('001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009','010')
 A<-c('2','2','1','1','2','0','2','0','1','0')
 B<-c('0','2','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0')
 C<-c('1','0','0','0','2','2','0','0','0','1')
 D<-c('1','0','1','1','0','2','1','1','2','2')
 E<-c('0','0','0','2','2','0','0','0','0','2')
 F<-c('0','1','1','1','0','0','2','0','0','0')
 data_test <- data.frame(PC, A, B, C, D, E, F)
```

And I have three chekboxGroupInputs named "variable1", "variable2" and "variable3".
Each of these chekboxGroupInputs has the following choices : "Yes" = "1", "No" = "2", "Perhaps" = "0".
When I check the choice "No" in the first chekboxGroupInput, the number of occurences displays "4" : ok, and if I check the choice "Perhaps" in the second chekboxGroupInput, the number of occurences is "2" : ok.
But if I uncheck the "Perhaps" box, the number of occurences is "0" instead of returning "4" like before.
Everything is ok when I check, but if I uncheck, the number of occurences drops to "0", and I don't understand why.
As I have dozens of variables in my dataframe, I will have as much chekboxGroupInputs as variables, so if you know a better way to do this, please, tell me.
Thank you very much for any help.
This is the reproducible example of my program :

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(shiny)

 ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(
     column(3,
            checkboxGroupInput("variable1", "Occurences of column A :",
                               c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                 "No (2)" = "2",
                                 "Perhaps (0)" = "0")),
            checkboxGroupInput("variable2", "Occurences of column B :",
                               c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                 "No (2)" = "2",
                                 "Perhaps (0)" = "0")),
            checkboxGroupInput("variable3", "Occurences of column C :",
                               c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                 "No (2)" = "2",
                                 "Perhaps (0)" = "0"))),

     column(3,
            tableOutput("data")),

     column(3,
            textOutput("result"))
     )
   )

 server <- function(input, output, session) {

   result <- 0

   observe({input$variable1

     output$result <- renderText({

       df1 <- filter(data_test, A %in% input$variable1)

       assign("df1", df1, envir = .GlobalEnv)

       result <- paste("Number of occurences = ", NROW(df1))

       })

     })

   observe({input$variable2

     if (is.null(input$variable2)){

       result <- paste("Number of occurences = ", NROW(df1))}

     else {

       output$result <- renderText({

         df2 <- filter(df1, B %in% input$variable2)

         assign("df2", df2, envir = .GlobalEnv)

         result <- paste("Number of occurences = ", NROW(df2))

         })

     }

     })

   observe({input$variable3

     if (is.null(input$variable3)){

       result <- paste("Number of occurences = ", NROW(df2)) }

     else {

       output$result <- renderText({

         df3 <- filter(df2, C %in% input$variable3)

         assign("df3", df3, envir = .GlobalEnv)

         result <- paste("Number of occurences = ", NROW(df3))

         })

     }

     })

   output$data <- renderTable({data_test})

 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example that works below. I made `df` a `reactive` (which means it should be called with `df()`), and put all the filters together. The `is.null(input$variable1)` is necessary because (I assume) you want all rows if nothing is selected.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
PC<-c('001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009','010')
A<-c('2','2','1','1','2','0','2','0','1','0')
B<-c('0','2','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0')
C<-c('1','0','0','0','2','2','0','0','0','1')
D<-c('1','0','1','1','0','2','1','1','2','2')
E<-c('0','0','0','2','2','0','0','0','0','2')
F<-c('0','1','1','1','0','0','2','0','0','0')
data_test <- data.frame(PC, A, B, C, D, E, F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           checkboxGroupInput("variable1", "Occurences of column A :",
                              c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                "No (2)" = "2",
                                "Perhaps (0)" = "0")),
           checkboxGroupInput("variable2", "Occurences of column B :",
                              c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                "No (2)" = "2",
                                "Perhaps (0)" = "0")),
           checkboxGroupInput("variable3", "Occurences of column C :",
                              c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                "No (2)" = "2",
                                "Perhaps (0)" = "0"))),

    column(3,
           tableOutput("data")),

    column(3,
           textOutput("result"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  result <- 0

  df1 <- reactive({
    filter(data_test,
           (is.null(input$variable1) | A %in% input$variable1),
           (is.null(input$variable2) | B %in% input$variable2),
           (is.null(input$variable3) | C %in% input$variable3))
  })

  output$result <- renderText(paste("Number of occurences = ", nrow(df1())))


  output$data <- renderTable({df1()})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, Bas, thank you very much, it's exactly what I wanted to get. I see that you put a vertical line in this : (is.null(input$variable1) | A %in% input$variable1). Would you know where I could find information about this vertical line please ? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! The bar is an 'or', you can find info by typing `?Logic` or `help("|")` in your R console, or going here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much Bas, Have a very nice day.